# Use sed with variable in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have the following :

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
sed -r "s/$i/ANON/g" /log > /test.txt
done
```

But the variable i doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By including the redirection into the loop, you're overwriting the `test.txt` with each iteration. You can instead use a loop to create a script for `sed` and process the file with it just once:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    printf 's/%s/ANON/g\n' "$i"
done | sed -r -f- /log > /test.txt
```

Or simply:

```
printf 's/%s/ANON/g\n' "${arr[@]}" | sed -r -f- /log > /test.txt
```

Note that it can still break if the array contains characters with special meaning in sed (that could even amount to a command injection vulnerability if the content of the array is not fully under your control).

Comment: So: the variable *does* work. Also you could use  >> to append to the file

Comment: @steffen This is a perfect case of a useless "this does not work" bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you'd like to replace all occurrences of any word in your array `arr` with the word `ANON`.

Your code works just fine, but you overwrite the output file for each iteration of the loop, which means that the final file will only have the last word in the array replaced.

There is also a potential issue if any of the words contain characters that may be interpreted as regular expression characters, like `*` and `[` for example.

It would be safer to do an exact string comparison for each replacement.  You may do this with `awk`:

```
{
    while (offset = index($0, str))
        $0 = substr($0, 1, offset - 1) "ANON" substr($0, offset + length(str))
}
{ print }
```

This would replace all occurrences of the value of `str` with the string `ANON`, even if `str` contained regular expression characters.

To read the strings from a file (with the added bonus that the second column of the tab-delimited string file contains the string to replace with):

```
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
NR == FNR { str[$1] = $2; next }
{
    for (s in str) {
        sl = length(s)
        while (offset = index($0, s))
            $0 = substr($0, 1, offset - 1) str[s] substr($0, offset + sl)
    }
}
{ print }
```

Given the tab-delimited strings file `strings` as

```
*password*    *redacted*
My Name       Not really my name
```

... and the text file `file.txt` as

```
Password for the account belonging to My Name: *password*
```

... the awk code would produce

```
Password for the account belonging to Not really my name: *redacted*
```

when run as

```
awk -f script.awk strings file.txt
```